# Ubuntu 16.04 fails to go into suspension mode

Tags: 16.04, suspend, power-management

I know the title sounds like many other threads already open, but my problem seems a little bit more unique, what happens is that most of the times i manually set my laptop into suspension mode, it goes into suspension mode for a few seconds and then it wakes up on its own, ive tried different ubuntu based distros but the problem remains, apart of that, i have issues with the xfce4-power-manager (i use LXDE), the laptop will go into suspension mode not in a regular way, sometimes it will and sometimes it doesn't. I apreciate any feedback. I upload a screenshot with the free -h command.
[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ZXn.png)

Comment: FIrst lets check your `swap space` run `free -h` and post it.

Comment: Put it in your post...